# How can i import Robot Keywords file from Python script and execute keywords from that file and generate report

Tags: python, robotframework

How can i import Robot Keywords file from Python script and execute keywords from that file and generate report like Robot html report.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import a robot keyword file from a python script, unless that script is using the low level robot API to run a test.

Robot keywords can only be used from within a running robot test.

Comment: Thanks for the Response, I m trying to use this code

Comment: from robot.api import TestSuite

from robot.api import ResourceFile

Res = ResourceFile('pathto/WIFIDataValidationFunctions.robot')

How can i call the keyword from the WIFIDataValidationFunctions.robot file

Comment: The comments on a question and answer should be used to ask questions. When you provide new information it should be updated in the question. Otherwise information is all over the place.